# Liferay spring mvc portlets webapplication context

Tags: spring, liferay

I have a single war file, which has 10 portlets in it.
So in each acc-portlet.xml (all 10 portlets.xml), I have added the spring inject beans declaration in it and I have common.xml, which has commonly used beans across portlets in it and imported this xml file using  tag in each of the portlets xml file.

And in the controller class of portlet I have implemented ApplicationContextAware.
When I print applicationcontext, i actually see 10 diff webapplicationcontext.

But as per my understanding (if I am not wrong) there should be only webapplicationcontext, as it is a single war.

And as I have imported the common.xml in each portlet, spring is instantiating singleton beans for each portlet.

See the log contents:

```
13:03:44,795 INFO  [XmlPortletApplicationContext:500] Refreshing PortletApplicationContext for namespace 'acc1-portlet': startup date [Thu Mar 21 13:03:44 GMT 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13:03:44,795 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315] Loading XML bean definitions from PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/acc1-portlet.xml]
13:03:44,827 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315] Loading XML bean definitions from PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/common.xml]
13:03:44,858 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory:581] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e894e0: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver#0,viewResolver,messageSource,jaxbMarshaller


13:03:44,795 INFO  [XmlPortletApplicationContext:500] Refreshing PortletApplicationContext for namespace 'bcc1-portlet': startup date [Thu Mar 21 13:03:44 GMT 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
13:03:44,795 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315] Loading XML bean definitions from PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/bcc1-portlet.xml]
13:03:44,827 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315] Loading XML bean definitions from PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/common.xml]
13:03:44,858 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory:581] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e894e0: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver#0,viewResolver,messageSource,jaxbMarshaller.
```

How can I make the common.xml contents to be loaded only once and have a signle spring applicationcontext?

Comment: Have you tried adding the application context config to web.xml instead?

Comment: Contents of my web.xml: <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml</param-value>            
 </context-param>...... in the applicationConext.xml, i just have bean for view resolver.

Comment: From the Spring docs (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html#portlet-dispatcher):
`In the Portlet MVC framework, each DispatcherPortlet has its own WebApplicationContext, which inherits all the beans already defined in the Root WebApplicationContext.` And your log file says you have single parent Root WebApplicationContext. So I see no problem here...

Comment: @EugeneEvdokimov I am worried this line: defining beans <pre> [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver#0,viewResolver,messageSource,jaxbMarshaller</pre>... i belive spring is instantiating beans for every portlet.

Comment: Spring singleton has only one instance per separate context or several contexts that are in parent-child relationship.
You could simply test it. For example try to initialize some instance field of any bean in your common.xml with the value of another incrementing static field and then compare values of bean instance fields from different portlets. They should be equal.